# Can the new http connector be used with the http:static-resource-handler in Mule 3.6?

Tags: mule

I have the following flow, attempting to use the new http connector in Mule 3.6 with the http:static-resource-handler:

```
  <flow name="facebook-sources-apiFlow1">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/admin" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:static-resource-handler resourceBase="${app.home}/web" defaultFile="index.html" doc:name="HTTP Static Resource Handler"/>
  </flow>
```

I have a directory called 'web' under src/main/app, and an index.html in the web directory.  When I try this, though, I get the following error:

```
null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: NullPayload
```

Before sinking too much time into the problem, I thought I'd ask if the new http connector even works with the static-resource-handler.

Comment: This was a bug in version 3.6.0 that has since been fixed. The one mentioned below is still open but most use cases should work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. There is a bug around this: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8317